# 7zip зависает, если есть файл это сокет

Tags: linux, архивация

linux ubuntu нужно сжать каталог с помощью 7zip.

Если в каталоге есть сокет (файл, в юниксе все файлы), то на нём 7zip подвисает и пишет "WARNING: Нет такого устройства или адреса" и все останавливается, не прерывается.

Можно ли каким-либо образом средствами 7zip (не используя find) исключить сокеты из списка файлов?

Comment: На сколько я понял проблема в том что этот файл постоянно меняется и поэтом 7zip никак не может его зазиповать? А есть конкретные шаги для воспроизведения, имя папки и т.п.?

Comment: Какая версия 7zip откуда скачанная? У меня в убунте с p7zip 16.02 повторить проблему не получается, сокеты успешно пакуются в 7z-архив

Comment: вот команда    7z a -tzip -mx6 -mmt=6  /res.7z ./* в текущем каталоге должны быть сокеты пример архива в корне чисто быстро написал, реально он не в корне

Comment: версия тоже 16.02, скачан из стандартного репозитория, apt

Comment: мне нужно уйти, прошу прощения.